# Catdoc xls2csv converting only one sheet

Tags: conversion, csv

I have Catdoc's `xls2csv` installed on Debian/Squeeze. It used to work beautifully when I copied files to a folder like `/var/www/xyz`, converting all sheets into `.csv` format, separated by `^L`.

But now, for whatever reason, it converts only the first sheet when I use the command:

```
xls2csv filename.xls > filename.csv
```

Any suggestions on what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, since CSV does not support multiple sheets.
You can select the sheet by the -b option.

```
xls2csv -b Sheet filename.xls > filename.csv
```

Refer `man xls2csv` for more options.

Comment: There seems to be at least 2 programs with the name `xls2csv`. The one that comes with Cygwin ("catdoc" package) does not do the same with `-b` and does not seem to have an option for getting only one sheet

Answer (score 0):

Using -b I still get all the worksheets dumped together in a single csv file. I passed the sheet name with `-b`.